# Android, Java: Room DB and/or RecyclerView don't update

Tags: java, android, android-room

In my app, the user can put in a date through a datepicker. When the user clicks a button, the difference to another date (which is taken from SharedPreferences) is calculated and both dates are converted to Strings. These 3 Strings are then saved in a Room DB. after all this is done, another activity is started, where a Recyclerview displays all objects of the database.

The problem is, that nothing is displayed in the recyclerview. There isn't even a error message, so I don't know where to start.
In this app, the same database stores already a different table. Its objects are also displayed with a recyclerview and there are no problems.

The Activity, where the date is typed in and saved:

```
public class NeuePeriodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityNeuePeriodeBinding binding;
    Zyklen zyklus;
    String laengeDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityNeuePeriodeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        binding.btnSpeichern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                neuePeriodeVorbereiten();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private View.OnClickListener neuePeriodeVorbereiten() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int tag = binding.datepickerNeuePeriode.getDayOfMonth();
        String monatStrFertig;
        String tagStrFertig;
        String jahr = Integer.toString(binding.datepickerNeuePeriode.getYear());
        int monat = binding.datepickerNeuePeriode.getMonth();
        monat += 1;
        if(tag<10){
            String tagStr = Integer.toString(tag);
            tagStrFertig = "0"+tagStr;
        }else{
            tagStrFertig = Integer.toString(tag);
        }
        if(monat<10){
            String monatStr = Integer.toString(monat);
            monatStrFertig = "0"+monatStr;
        }else{
            monatStrFertig = Integer.toString(monat);
        }
        String aktuellePeriode = tagStrFertig+"-"+monatStrFertig+"-"+jahr;

        zyklusLaengeAusrechnen(aktuellePeriode, prefs);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String letztePeriode = prefs.getString("letztePeriode", "");
        LocalDate date1 = parse(letztePeriode, formatter);
        LocalDate date2 = parse(aktuellePeriode, formatter);
        date2 = date2.minusDays(1);
        DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        zyklus = new Zyklen();
        zyklus.setLaenge(laengeDb);
        zyklus.setStart(df.format(date1));
        zyklus.setEnde(df.format(date2));

        Intent intent = new Intent(NeuePeriodeActivity.this, ZusammenfassungActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("zyklus", zyklus);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);

        neuePeriodeInPrefsSpeichern(aktuellePeriode, prefs);
        return null;
    }

    private String zyklusLaengeAusrechnen(String neuePeriode, SharedPreferences prefs) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String letztePeriode = prefs.getString("letztePeriode", "");
        int laenge = Integer.parseInt(prefs.getString("laenge", ""));
        LocalDate date1 = parse(letztePeriode, formatter);
        LocalDate date2 = parse(neuePeriode, formatter);
        long differenz = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(date1, date2.plusDays(1));
        laengeDb = Long.toString(differenz);
        int differenzKonvertiert = Long.valueOf(differenz).intValue();
        int durchschnitt = (differenzKonvertiert+laenge)/2;
        String fertigeLaenge = String.valueOf(durchschnitt);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("laenge", fertigeLaenge);
        editor.commit();
        return laengeDb;
    }

    public void neuePeriodeInPrefsSpeichern(String letztePeriode, SharedPreferences prefs) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("letztePeriode", letztePeriode);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

The activity, where the recyclerview should display the objects:

```
public class ZusammenfassungActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityZusammenfassungBinding binding;
    RoomDB database_zyklen;
    ZyklenListeAdapter zyklenListeAdapter;
    List<Zyklen> zyklen = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityZusammenfassungBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = binding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        database_zyklen = RoomDB.getInstance(this);
        zyklen = database_zyklen.zyklenDao().getAll();

        updateRecycler(zyklen);

        binding.buttonTagebuch.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            Intent tagebuchActivity = new Intent(ZusammenfassungActivity.this, TagebuchActivity.class);
            startActivity(tagebuchActivity);
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 101){
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                Zyklen neuerZyklus = (Zyklen) data.getSerializableExtra("zyklus");
                database_zyklen.zyklenDao().insert(neuerZyklus);
                zyklen.clear();
                zyklen.addAll(database_zyklen.zyklenDao().getAll());
                zyklenListeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateRecycler(List<Zyklen> zyklen) {
        binding.recyclerviewZyklen.setHasFixedSize(true);
        binding.recyclerviewZyklen.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        zyklenListeAdapter = new ZyklenListeAdapter(ZusammenfassungActivity.this, zyklen);
        binding.recyclerviewZyklen.setAdapter(zyklenListeAdapter);
    }
}
```

The adapter for the recyclerview:

```
public class ZyklenListeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ZyklenViewHolder> {

    Context context;
    List<Zyklen> liste;

    public ZyklenListeAdapter(Context context, List<Zyklen> liste){
        this.context = context;
        this.liste = liste;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ZyklenViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ZyklenViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.zyklen_liste, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ZyklenViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textview_beschreibung.setText(liste.get(position).getStart()+" - "+liste.get(position).getStart()+", "+liste.get(position).getLaenge()+" Tage");
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return liste.size();
    }
}

class ZyklenViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cardview_zyklencontainer;
    TextView textview_beschreibung;

    public ZyklenViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardview_zyklencontainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_zyklencontainer);
        textview_beschreibung = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textview_beschreibung);
    }
}
```

I'm kinda lost, every help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There's no database insertion code in the neuePeriodeVorbereiten function. You're creating a Zyklen object but not inserting it into the database.

If you want to receive a result from another activity you should use startActivityForResult(). You aren't using startActivityForResult anywhere to start NeuePeriodeActivity, hence onActivityResult will not be triggered when you return from NeuePeriodeActivity

Also: The onActivityResult method is now deprecated. Instead, use the new Activity Result API.

Comment: Thanks. I used methods without really knowing what they do, ofc there will be errors.